# Angular - Combine two observables results into one

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have two nodes in my database - one which is `allUsers` and one which is `usersChildren`.

For example:

```
allUsers: { user1: {...}, user2: {...}}
usersChildren: { user1: {...} }
```

In this case `user1` has children data and `user2` does not.

I want to retrieve a list of all user objects, and inside each user's object I wish to add the children data from the `usersChildren` node(if there is one).

However, I am not really familiar with how I can do that. I have tried the following but this results in obtaining only the children information and not 
a combined object with both the children information and the user meta data.

```
this.af.getObservable(`allUsers`).pipe(map(allUsers =>
    allUsers.map(user => this.af.getObservable(`usersChildren/${user.id}`)))
   .subscribe(allUsersData => this.userList = allUsersData);
```

What is the best way to achieve what I desire?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
this.af.getObservable(`allUsers`)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(users => forkJoin(
      users.map(user => this.af.getObservable(`usersChildren/${user.id}`))
    ))
  );
```

You make an HTTP call to get all the users, then you use `forkJoin` to make 1 call per user. The call is made thank to `Array.map`, which transforms your user into an HTTP call.

Now you can subscribe to it like this

```
this.myService.getAllUsers().subscribe(users => { console.log(users); });
```

Comment: This way I do not obtain any result. It's like forkJoin does not emit at all neither the subscribe. Can you offer a workaround for this?

Comment: If this code isn't triggered, then your previous code isn't triggered. You must have changed something else.

Answer (score 0):

I would use **concat** operator in your case.

Concat will combine two observables into a combined sequence, but the second observable will not start emitting until the first one has completed.

Example:

```
let first = Observable.timer(10,500).map(r => {
  return {source:1,value:r};
}).take(4);
let second = Observable.timer(10,500).map(r => {
  return {source:2,value:r};
}).take(4);
first.concat(second).subscribe(res => this.concatStream.push(res));
```